# android binding to a service from an activityto get hold of a populated hashmap

Tags: android, service

Would you suggest using the steps mentioned in the blog below to bind to a running service?  I need a way to get hold of a populated hashmap from my service.

http://www.ozdroid.com/#!BLOG/2010/12/19/How_to_make_a_local_Service_and_bind_to_it_in_Android

Instead of working with and returning a database, I would like to return a hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can use what is described below

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html